# Is there a way to have a function within a controller to check for something then redirect user to another page be in just one line

Tags: laravel

I created a function in a controller that would do both checking and possible redirecting to another page if needed

I want to make this happen in just one line but had to resort making it three with two functions to make it work. It would help if there's a way to make one function do both checking and redirecting to another page

Aside from using Middlewares, I'm just looking for an easier way to do this since there are other kinds of checks/redirects I want to implement in different controllers. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the original function or not. If there's no other way, I'll just do the longer method or use Middlewares

I wanted to do something like this at first:

```
public static function redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder(Order $order)
{
    if ($order->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
        return redirect()
            ->route('orders.index')
            ->with('status', 'You are not authorized to view this order');
    }
}

public function order(Order $order)
{
    self::redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order);

    return view('orders.show', compact('order'));
}

public function payPage(Order $order)
{
    self::redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order);

    return view('orders.pay', compact('order'));
}
```

Since the `redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder` function returns a redirect and it's not doing anything in the `order` and `payPage` functions, the page just returns their view skipping the redirect earlier

I had to resort to having two different methods:

```
public static function redirectToOrdersPageAndWarnUser()
{
    return redirect()
        ->route('orders.index')
        ->with('status', 'You are not authorized to view this order');
}

public static function shouldUserSeeOrder(Order $order)
{
    return $order->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
}

public function order(Order $order)
{
    if (!self::shouldUserSeeOrder($order)) {
        return self::redirectToOrdersPageAndWarnUser($order);
    }

    return view('orders.show', compact('order'));
}

public function payPage(Order $order)
{
    if (!self::shouldUserSeeOrder($order)) {
        return self::redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order);
    }

    return view('orders.pay', compact('order'));
}
```

Comment: It's better to make such checks on the middleware side. Ideally, not authorized user shouldn't pass to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you should use middlewares for this.
but may this help you

```
    public static function redirectToOrdersPageAndWarnUser()
    {
        return redirect()
            ->route('orders.index')
            ->with('status', 'You are not authorized to view this order');
    }

    public static function shouldUserSeeOrder(Order $order)
    {
        return $order->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
    }

    public static function redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order)
    {
        return static::shouldUserSeeOrder($order) ? null : self::redirectToOrdersPageAndWarnUser();
    }

    public function order(Order $order)
    {
        return static::redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order)
            ?? view('orders.show', compact('order'));
    }

    public function payPage(Order $order)
    {
        return static::redirectIfUserShouldNotSeeOrder($order)
            ?? view('orders.pay', compact('order'));
    }
```